# Hue Solr Marker Map limited to 25

Tags: solr, cloudera, marker, hue

When displaying data in a Hue Dashboard (Data from a Solr Server - not in cloud mode) the marker map is only displaying 25 "markers". Is there any way to adjust this limit?
If I filter the data it will adjust to these filters, but again limited to 25 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1

By default only 25 results are returned to you would need to bump this via the Grid Result pagination.

## 2

Then you might hit some configuration of Leaflet. The map is based on http://leafletjs.com and is used by Hue https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/desktop/core/src/desktop/js/ext/leaflet